# Looping track with soundpool

Tags: android, audio, loops, media-player, soundpool

i need to loop without lag a music in my app. In android < 4.0 I used mediaplayer and all went right. In android > 4.0 the same code is not able to loop without an important lag.

So I tried to use SoundPool. If I use

```
int NO_LOOP=0;
sp.play(ID, 1, 1, 0, NO_LOOP, 1);
```

The sound play without problems, but if I use

```
int LOOP=-1;
sp.play(ID, 1, 1, 0, LOOP, 1);
```

It doesn't work and this message appears:

```
08-21 05:12:48.243: E/AudioTrack(15035): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
08-21 05:12:48.243: E/SoundPool(15035): Error creating AudioTrack
```

What is wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do gapless looping you must use WAV files that are under 1mb.  Otherwise the -1 setting for looping will cause your files to just not play.

This worked, just tested it.

Comment: So, how can I play sound that are over 1mb gapless? I can't believe that there is no way...

Comment: There is a way with using MediaPlayer class.